# vector iterators incompatible error

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

I'm getting a vector iterators incompatible error during runtime. the line where it happens is at the very end of the code section, inside the for loop (humans.push_back( Human(&deck, (*iter)) );)
When I first got the error, I was using a different iterator than 'iter' by mistake, so the runtime error totally made sense. But now that I changed it and recompiled everything (I double checked that), I still get this error.

```
void BlackjackGame::getHumansAndHouse()
{
    // asks how many players, pushes_back vector accordingly, initializes house, checking for valid input throughout
    string input;
    vector<string> names;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "How many humans? (1 - 7)" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if(!isdigit(input[0]))
            cout << "Invalid input. ";
        else
        {
            input.erase(1);
            int j = atoi(input.c_str());
            for(int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    cout << "Enter player " << i << " name: ";
                    cin >> input;
                    if(strcmp(input.c_str(), "House") == 0)
                        cout << "Player name has to be different than 'House'." << endl;
                    else
                    {
                        names.push_back(input);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    vector<string>::iterator iter;
    for(iter = names.begin(); iter != names.end(); iter++)
        humans.push_back( Human(&deck, (*iter)) );

    house = House(&deck);
}
```

humans is a vector:

```
vector<Human> humans;
```

where Human is a class whose constructor is as follows:

```
Human(Deck *d, string n) : Player(d), name(n) { printNameCardsAndTotal(); }
```

(Human is a derived class of Player)

since iter is an iterator to a vector of strings, I don't understand why I get vector iterators incompatible in that line inside the for loop. It's not like I'm trying to use iter directly with humans.

error is here:

```
humans.push_back( Human(&deck, (*iter)) );
```

Comment: Will you please post the code where the `names` and `humans` vectors are defined, as well as the actual error output?

Comment: names' iterator was on top of my code, I moved it to the bottom for clarity. the actual vector names is on top of the code section. and i posted humans as well.

Comment: Where's `deck` declared?

Comment: OK, I see the vector and iterator definitions now, sorry about that. How about the compiler or runtime output (the error message, in a straight copy from your terminal and paste into a code box format)?

Comment: class BlackjackGame
{
 Deck deck;    ...

Comment: note that I tried what B tyler suggested, that is, humans.push_back( Human(&deck, "foo") ); and I still get the error. so weird!

Comment: error....include/.../vector line 238 expression: vector iterators incompatible

Comment: What's the *exact* error message.  It might also help to know what compiler and platform you're working with.

Comment: Does your `Human` class have a copy constructor and/or a destructor?  Are there raw pointers inside `Human` that need explicit explicit management?

Comment: visualc++ express 2010, windows 7. the error is in terminal, copy paste doesn't work here. but it says: debug assertion failed! program:(directory of prog) file:(directory of include\vector) expression: vector iterators incompatible

Comment: my Human class does not have a copy constructor. could that be the problem?

Comment: @Edoz: without knowing more about `class Human` it's impossible to say whether you need to provide a copy constructor or if the compiler generated copy ctor is OK.

Comment: I also tried humans.push_back( *(new Human(&deck, (*iter))) ); it should have solved if the problem was a copy constructor, right? but it didn't

Comment: @Edoz: No, it can't solve the problem with copy ctor it it was. It is just a way of loosing some memory..

Comment: my class human only has a const string variable and a member function. its base class Player, however, has vectors and iterators and a pointer as member variables. does that mean I need a copy ctor for that class?

Comment: Please provide a *self-contained* example. *"self-contained"* means that the source code is intended for compilation and execution without any dependencies other than the standard library.

Comment: turns out I did not need copy constructors, but oswald was right, I had errors in other parts of my code which were called at the constructors of Player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in code that you do not show. The following code, which I have written based on your code and your descriptions, does not produce any errors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class Deck
{
};

class Player()
{
  public:
    Player(Deck *d) {}
};

class Human : public Player
{
  public:
    Human(Deck *d, string n) : Player(d), name(n) {}
  private:
    string name;
};

class House
{
  public:
    House(Deck *d) {}
};

int main()
{
    Deck deck;
    vector<Human> humans;
    string input;
    vector<string> names;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "How many humans? (1 - 7)" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if(!isdigit(input[0]))
            cout << "Invalid input. ";
        else
        {
            input.erase(1);
            int j = atoi(input.c_str());
            for(int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    cout << "Enter player " << i << " name: ";
                    cin >> input;
                    if(strcmp(input.c_str(), "House") == 0)
                        cout << "Player name has to be different than 'House'." << endl;
                    else
                    {
                        names.push_back(input);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    vector<string>::iterator iter;
    for(iter = names.begin(); iter != names.end(); iter++)
        humans.push_back( Human(&deck, (*iter)) );

    House house = House(&deck);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try

```
iter != names.end()
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but the error is in the next line! (I tried just in case, it doesn't solve the problem). By the way, is using != faster?

Comment: @Edoz: It's likely to make no difference for `std::vector`. `std::vector` has random access iterators so it's perfectly fine to use `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Always pre-increment iterators in a for loop and use `it != end` as your sentinel in C++ (this also goes for `int`s.

```
for(iter = names.begin(); iter **!=** names.end(); **++iter**)
```

Comment: is ++iter different than iter++? anyway I tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: note that the error is INSIDE the for loop, not at the 'declaration' of it (I checked with breakpoints)

Comment: Yes ++iter is different, but it shouldn't make a difference here. Try `for(iter = names.begin(); iter != names.end(); iter++) humans.push_back( Human(&deck, string("foo") );` and see if that works to begin with, if it does then you know that there is something going on with `iter`.

Comment: thanks for the tip, yes, I still get the error using 'foo'. it means the problem is not iter! but then why do I get an iterator error?

Comment: Try `for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) humans.push_back( Human(&deck, string("foo") );` and see if you still get an error.

Comment: @B Tyler: why pre-increment the iterator in general? It is not advice I've heard before, so I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind it. Is it an [Effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201924889) recommendation?

Comment: Firstly for iterators it is always more efficient because it avoids making a copy of the iterator (for `int` types there is no performance gain). Secondly if you get into the habit of using it all the time for all data types (unless you explicitly need a post increment) then you will be optimising your code for free without thinking. It is just a good habit. Also if you always use `!=` in your for loops then you can swap seamlessly between `int` and `iterator` without any change in syntax. (it might be Effective C++, can't remember)

Comment: @Josh Glover: you can find it in item 6 of [More Effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/More-Effective-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/020163371X)

Comment: Could it be a copy ctor problem?

Comment: Yes, you must have a copy constructor defined for a type to be used in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft `<vector>` header implementation has some debugging checks enabled in your build that make iterators much richer objects than mere pointers - they keep track of the container they're iterating through and their 'neighbor' iterators as well as the object they're pointing to. The assertion you're running into is checking that 2 iterators that should be pointing into the same container, but it's finding that they don't (according to the iterators' state).

So you're either corrupting the iterator objects/lists somewhere or you're doing something that isn't shown in your code snippets.